# Move object in straight line swift

Tags: swift

I have an image and I need to move it in a straight line for example from (x, y) to (x1, y2).

And after moving how do I make the image disappear?

I tried to do this but I don´t know what to do next.

```
@IBOutlet weak var moveobj: UIImageView!
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    linePath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100))
    linePath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 300, y: 300))
    moveobj.layer .addAnimation(path, forKey: "path")
}
```

Comment: Make the image disappear by doing `moveobj.isHidden = true`

Comment: okey thank you , and now how to move ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    // Set the image view in the starting location
    moveobj.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: /* some width */, height: /* some height */)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: /* some duration */, animations: {
        // Move image view to new location
        self.moveobj.frame = CGRect(x: 300, y: 300, width: self.moveobj.frame.width, height: self.moveobj.frame.height)
    }) { (finished) in
        // Animation completed; hide the image view
        self.moveobj.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

Comment: i have one erro with "UIView.animation(withDuration: /* some duration */, animations:{...}" its say type "Uiview  " has no member "animation " how i do now ?  thanks for answer

Comment: Spelling error on my part. Should be `animate(withDuration:...)`

Comment: because its still same erro

Comment: `animate(withDuration:...)` is a class func on `UIView`. So the `UIView` is necessary, e.g. `UIView.animate(withDuration:...)`.

Comment: already put its okey thanks but now i have erro with Value of type 'UIImageView' has no member 'isHidden'

Comment: @dinis, in Swift 3 it's `.isHidden`, before that it's just  `.hidden`

Comment: sorry move one question for example if i would like to display again this after 5 second how i do this i try to put this but i have erro: NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(4, target: self, selector: self.moveobj, userInfo: nil, repeats: false)